# while scrolling in recycler view it added some other values to the selected list of checkboxes

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-checkbox

Here you can see I have plist in which I'm fetching the selected checkboxes when user clicks on `select all` button.

Here is that when I show the list of data. There is only the data of those checkboxes which are visible on screen and when I scroll down, remaining checkboxes get selected and when I scroll some more time it another repeated values of selected checkboxes

Adapter.java

```
public class AttendanceRegisterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttendanceRegisterAdapter.AttendanceViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    private ArrayList<Student> student;
    private boolean isSelectedAll;
    private ArrayList<String> plist = new ArrayList<>();

    public AttendanceRegisterAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Student> student) {
        this.context = context;
        this.student = student;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AttendanceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_card_student, parent, false);

        return new AttendanceViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void selectAll() {
        isSelectedAll = true;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void unSelectAll() {
        isSelectedAll = false;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AttendanceViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Student selectedList = student.get(position);

        holder.cbAttendance.setSelected(selectedList.getSelected());
        holder.cbAttendance.setTag(position);

        if (isSelectedAll) {
            selectedList.setSelected(true);
            plist.add(student.get(position).getStudentID());
        } else {
            selectedList.setSelected(false);
            plist.remove(student.get(position).getStudentID());
        }

        holder.cbAttendance.setChecked(selectedList.getSelected());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return student.size();
    }



    class AttendanceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cvStudentCard;
        ImageView imgStudentPicture;
        TextView txtStudentName;
        CheckBox cbAttendance;


        public AttendanceViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cvStudentCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_student_view);
            imgStudentPicture = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_student_picture);
            txtStudentName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_card_title);
            cbAttendance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_attendance);


        }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello Welcome to SO. What is the actual question here ?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding **StudentId** in BindViewHolder without checking **plist**
maybe duplicate values are added each time BindViewHolder is called.

```
public class AttendanceRegisterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttendanceRegisterAdapter.AttendanceViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    private ArrayList<Student> student;
    private boolean isSelectedAll;
    private ArrayList<String> plist = new ArrayList<>();

    public AttendanceRegisterAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Student> student) {
        this.context = context;
        this.student = student;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AttendanceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_card_student, parent, false);

        return new AttendanceViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void selectAll() {
        isSelectedAll = true;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void unSelectAll() {
        isSelectedAll = false;
        
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
   
    public Boolean checkElementExist(String element) {
        return plist.contains(element);
    }
    
    public void selectLeftOver(int nextPosition) {
        for (int i = nextPosition; nextPosition > getItemCount(); i++) {
            if (!checkElementExist(student.get(i).getStudentID())) {
                plist.add(student.get(i).getStudentID());
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AttendanceViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Student selectedList = student.get(position);

        holder.cbAttendance.setSelected(selectedList.getSelected());
        holder.cbAttendance.setTag(position);

        if (isSelectedAll) {
            selectedList.setSelected(true);
            if (!checkElementExist(student.get(position).getStudentID())) {
                plist.add(student.get(position).getStudentID());
                selectLeftOver(position + 1);
                }
            
        } else {
            selectedList.setSelected(false);
            if (!checkElementExist(student.get(position).getStudentID())) {
                plist.remove(student.get(position).getStudentID());
                }
            
        }

        holder.cbAttendance.setChecked(selectedList.getSelected());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return student.size();
    }



    class AttendanceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cvStudentCard;
        ImageView imgStudentPicture;
        TextView txtStudentName;
        CheckBox cbAttendance;


        public AttendanceViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cvStudentCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_student_view);
            imgStudentPicture = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_student_picture);
            txtStudentName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_card_title);
            cbAttendance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_attendance);


        }
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks this solution worked but one more problem is that it adds the values of only that checkboxes which are visible on the screen. Like I have 20 checkboxes and 2 button. One for showing selected and one for selecting all. If user will press select all button then it adds only the 15 checkboxes which are visible on screen when I scroll down and when those remaining checkboxes gets visible then next time it shows the another 5 checkboxes value

Comment: problem is with BindViewHolder. this method is executed only recyclerView is fetching the data of its list item to show(visible). In your case, if 15 checkboxes are visible without scrolling that means only 15 times BindViewHolder is called and executed. when you scroll down to view the remaining 5 Items than BindViewHolder is called another 5 times. so, that's the problem. I have edited my code to fix this try now..